# How to design timeline view in flutter

Tags: flutter, timeline

I want to design the timeline view similar to the image below. I tried searching but couldn't find any way to design this view. I want to show data based on date. Does anyone know how I can do this? Or any plugin please suggest me.  [image]

Comment: you can check this package : https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_tile